# repeater item give me null value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have button to provide voting functionality. I use a `usercontrol`.
I get the following exception:

> > object reference is null

Here is the code

```
protected void btnVot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Save Data
        sqlCon = DBConnection.GetConnection(string.Empty);

        if (sqlCon != null)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpAnswers.Items)
            {
                if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    VotingAnswers AnswerObj = (VotingAnswers )item.DataItem;
                    HtmlInputRadioButton rbMyRadio = (HtmlInputRadioButton)item.FindControl("rbMyRadio");

                    if (rbMyRadio != null && rbMyRadio.Checked)
                    {
                        VotAns.AnswerCount = +1;
                        VotAns.AnswerRatio = (VotAns.AnswerCount * 100) / 100;

                        if (VotAnswerDAO.Update(sqlCon, VotAns))
                        {
                            divQuestion.Visible = false;
                            divVoting.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlCon != null)
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
            sqlCon.Dispose();
        }
    }
    VotingAnswers AnswerObj = (VotingAnswers )item.DataItem;   //is giving me null
```

Could you please help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: Please explain some brief so user can understand your issue  - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add condition over there

```
if(item != null && item.DataItem != null)
{
// Do code....
}
```

This is not proper solution but it's now helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

I did some refactoring in your code:

```
protected void btnVot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Save Data
        sqlCon = DBConnection.GetConnection(string.Empty);
        if (sqlCon == null)
            return;

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpAnswers.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                continue;

            VotingAnswers AnswerObj = (VotingAnswers )item.DataItem;
            HtmlInputRadioButton rbMyRadio = (HtmlInputRadioButton)item.FindControl("rbMyRadio");

            if (rbMyRadio == null || !rbMyRadio.Checked)
                continue;

            VotAns.AnswerCount = +1;
            VotAns.AnswerRatio = (VotAns.AnswerCount * 100) / 100;

            if (VotAnswerDAO.Update(sqlCon, VotAns))
            {
                divQuestion.Visible = false;
                divVoting.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        VotingAnswers AnswerObj = (VotingAnswers)item.DataItem;        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Do some exception handling here
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlCon != null)
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
            sqlCon.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and move the line:

```
VotingAnswers AnswerObj = (VotingAnswers)item.DataItem;
```

to a safer position.

To answer your question, if there is no db connection or the event is triggered by a header or footer in your repeater, the exception will be thrown.

Comment: if you found it useful you can mark it as the answer and vote it up